How to use a "reverse percentage"/unitless calculation in a CSS calc()?
I would like to use the following calculation in the width and height of an element:
(1 / 0.65) * 100, then the % sign

So that the width & height are set to 153.85%.
However I believe the first number must have units, or be a percentage - in order for calc to work.
How can I set this in calc rather than hardcoding it to 153.85%?
153.85% being the reverse percentage of 65% - per this Math.SE question.
I tried calc(100% / 65%) but this was marked as invalid syntax.

Maybe try it like this: calc((100% * 100) / 65);

@l'L'l Nice, that works thank you! Would you like to post an answer and I'll accept? Thanks again! ....actually I just figured out that calc(100% / 0.65) works too

You can convert the percentage into "raw" form, and then do your calculation:
calc((100% * 100) / 65);

(100% * 100) / 65 behaves consistently and correctly in css because it correctly manipulates units according to css rules. (100% / 0.65) uses direct division of a percentage by a unitless number and might not be supported by different browsers consistently. Also using the method shown above maintains the percentage throughout the calculation, whereas the latter does not.

You could try to use 100vh/vw instead of 100%:
height: calc(100vh / 0.65);
width: calc(100vw / 0.65);


Maybe transform: scale(calc(1/0.65),calc(1/0.65))
I updated my coment.

This works actually, I apologise, thank you! (the 100vw part, not the transform part)
